# change to random subdirectory in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to change to a random subdirectory in a folder with batch

```
cd c:\*
```

doesnt work, in fact takes you to the recycle bin each time

```
if exist * (
cd *
)
```

didnt work

```
for %d in (*) do cd %d
```

didnt work

so im at a loss, is there any way to do this in batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Create an array of dir. names
set n=0
for /D %%a in (c:\*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set dir[!n!]=%%a
)
rem Select a random element from the array
set /A d=%random%*n/32768+1
rem And CD to it
cd "!dir[%d%]!"
```

Comment: perfect! just what i needed

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set c=0
rem count dirs in c:\
for /d %%I in (c:\*) do set /a c+=1 >NUL
set /a c=%RANDOM% * %c% / 32768 + 1 >NUL
set loop=0
for /d %%I in (c:\*) do (
    set /a loop+=1
    if !loop!==%c% cd /d "%%I"
)
```